# Drupal 7 ajax command with effect

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

The Drupal 7 AJAX library is great, very easy to use. However, I cannot find any resources that can explain to me how to add some effects when the ajax happens. for example, when i use ajax_command_replace to dynamically replace content with certain div, how can I make it fade in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax/7
In the AJAX array, you can add an item "effect" and set it to slide, fade, or none (defaults to none). To make your item fade in, here's what you write:

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'wrapper' => ...,
  'callback' => ...,
  'effect' => 'fade'
),
```

Comment: But where do you place the single array if you are just using commands?

Answer (score 2):

according to [this link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)

> ajax['effect']: The jQuery effect to use when placing the new HTML.
>   Defaults to no effect. Valid options are 'none', 'slide', or 'fade'.**

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the effect goes in as a new entry in the array returned by `ajax_command_*`.

For example:

```
$command = ajax_command_replace('#my-container', $html);
$command['effect'] = 'slide';
```